# Why does my asian text web page show up on windows 7 but not on server 2003?

Tags: windows-7, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-server-2003

Ive written a webpage with some asian characters. When I view it with a web browser using windows 7 the text shows up properly. However when I use server 2003 it shows up as lots of squares. Whats going on? I saved the page as UTF-8 and I put UTF-8 in the html header as the content type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squares usually mean "The computer knows this character, but can't render the glyph". In other words: you don't have the necessary fonts.

Since Windows 7 is a end-user OS and Server 2003 is a server OS, it's very possible that the latter only has a limited set of fonts installed by default.

Installing additional fonts and/or installing language packs will probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed language pack and setup correctly other regional options on you server 2003 system?

Comment: No probably not I just wanted to know what the issue was rather than solve it. Im developing a webpage with chinese characters on so obviously chinese people will have thos language packs installed.